# Add Column using Doctrine to live site

Tags: codeigniter, doctrine

I'm about to push a site I've been developing using Code Igniter and Doctrine live.

I want to push it live in it's current state, but know I'll be adding features in the future that might require changing columns, changing enum values, and adding columns to my doctrine records.

Up to now I've been just dropping tables and recreating them using:

```
Doctrine::createTablesFromModels();
```

Obviously this isn't possible one the database starts filling up with live data. How can I add and alter the columns without dropping and recreating the tables from models each time?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Migrations](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/migrations/en)

Comment: When I make a migration class, do I also need to change my codeigniter model before performing the migration? Or will my model always be the same as when I launch? it looks like I can just change the models and call: Doctrine_Core::generateMigrationsFromModels and it will write the migrations for me?

Comment: Im not sure, i never manually write my models, i always build from YAML and when i do migrations i use the `generateMigrationsDiff`, add anything i need to add to migrate actual data, run the migration, then rebuild my model from my YAML.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I have Doctrine setup as a plugin right now (as described here: http://www.phpandstuff.com/articles/codeigniter-doctrine-from-scratch-day-1-install-and-setup) and I haven't been using YAML. Thanks for the guidance. I'll have to see what I can figure out.